# ASP.NET Core MVC Register/Login Pages not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am following Tim Corey's video on "ASP.NET Core MVC" and I've created a test project with a register/login authentication system using Identity (in .NET 6.0).

My issue is that the Register and Login pages do not work. The page stays the same.

[This is what I am getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC5Mk.png)

[What I want is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6YsV.png)

I followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

I added the tag  in the _Layout.cshtml file.

I followed other stackoverflow questions that said to download Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Identity into an existing MVC project, we can find detailed steps from ["Scaffold Identity into an MVC project without existing authorization"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization) section in same doc that you referenced.

*Adding the login partial (`_LoginPartial`) to the `_Layout.cshtml` file to include Register and Login pages. And ASP.NET Core Identity is implemented as a Razor Class Library, your MVC project does not support endpoints for Razor Pages by default, to make it works well, adding `MapRazorPages` to `Program.cs`  is required.*

Comment: I have been able to scaffold pages in past projects to customize those pages with net7.0, but now my new project is not using the pages from the Identity Area.  It seems no matter what it continues to use the default pages and not my "overridden" ones.  I've followed the page to add the packages, literally pasting them in, and when I click Register or Login I still see the default pages. Has anyone else seen this and fixed it?  I also started getting errors not able to find the routes unless I add AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() in Program.cs after running the identiyt scaffolding wizard.